# How can I make Google "My Maps" use miles?

Tags: google-maps, google-my-maps

I'm creating a map using Google [My Maps](https://mapsengine.google.com/map/u/0/). It works pretty well, but the "measure distances and areas" tool seems to work exclusively in km, even though I'm creating a map in London, and have English set as my language. Is there a way I can make it display distances in miles instead?

Comment: "My Maps" has been folded into the general Google Maps. This question would appear to be moot.

Comment: @ale they are still distinct, although the difference is obscure in a frustrating way. Compare https://www.google.com/maps/ and https://www.google.com/maps/d/. They share some but not all functionality.

Answer (score 1):

Down in the lower-right corner there should be a scale indicator (in km).

> [image: screen snippet showing km]

Just click it. Then your units will switch to miles. Click again to switch back.

> [image: screen snippet showing miles]

If you're zoomed in, it'll change the units (feet vs. meters) but it works the same.

Comment: That sounds plausible, but there is no scale indicator as you describe; I see it on regular Google Maps, but not when I am creating my own map using My Maps.

Comment: That's odd. I specifically went into "My Maps" to create the screen shots.

Comment: I could prove it if I could attach screenshots to the comments :) I wonder if you are using 'old' Google Maps? https://support.google.com/maps/answer/4398222?hl=en

Comment: Incidentially, if I visit "regular" Google Maps (https://www.google.co.uk/maps/), I do see the links you show in your screenshots. They don't seem to affect my "My Map", though.

Comment: _" I wonder if you are using 'old' Google Maps?"_ Oh, no, I am definitely using the new Google Maps.